# Eclipse c++11 // vector

Tags: c++, eclipse, multithreading, vector, c++11

This is really driving me crazy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void test() {
    vector<string> myvector;
    string a("Teststring");
    myvector.push_back(a);
    cout << myvector.begin()->length() << endl;
}

int main() {
    thread(test).join();
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles fine with the  -std=c++11 flag to the compiler and the -pthread flag to the linker.

BUT: Eclipse does either know the std::thread or the myvector.begin()->length(), even if the code runs fine eclipse warns me **"Method 'length' could not be resolved"**.

I tried every possible solution in here: [Eclipse CDT C++11/C++0x support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support) without any success. This took me so many hours now, what am I doing wrong?!

Is there anybody getting a project setup without problems with this code?

**EDIT: Other code example - same problem:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>


using namespace std;

class TestClass {
public:
    void test() {
        cout << "test" << endl;
    }
};

void test() {
    vector<TestClass> testClassVector;
    TestClass x;
    testClassVector.push_back(x);
    testClassVector.begin()->test();
}

int main() {
    thread(test).join();

    return 0;
}
```

Compiles and runs correct, but returns in eclipse: **Method 'test' could not be resolved**

**EDIT:**

*working versions:*

```
((TestClass)*(testClassVector.begin())).test();

TestClass foo2 = *(testClassVector.begin());
    foo2.test();
```

*still not working:*

```
testClassVector.begin()->test();
```

The last compiles and works like the two above, but eclipse still claims:

*Method 'test' could not be resolved*

Comment: Try '#include <string>'

Comment: Tried, doesn't solve the problem..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm wrong, but I think your problem don't come from Eclypse. Juste, begin() on a vector return a `std::vector<T>::iterator` first, this is not a pointer and there is no method length, but you can ask for the vector size with `myvector.size();` if this is what you want. 
The problem could come from your `#include <string.h>` that is not the same as `#include <string>`, string.h is for string operation like strcmp, strstr, etc... juste string will define the std::string object.

Comment: I think the point is printing the length of the string which is 10 characters long.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, my bad. So, the problem must come frome the string.h include against juste string. I edit it.

Comment: As described here: http://www.mochima.com/tutorials/vectors.html you can access methods via this pointer. Or is there any other way doing this?

Comment: ...I also added a second code block without string having the exactly same problem..

Comment: An alternative of the -> operator is to use ther * operator, look :
`testClassVector.begin()->test();` can be write as : 
`(*testClassVector.begin()).test();`
Maybe the ->operator isn't functionnal

Comment: Just to be clear: the compiling works and it prints "test" after running without any problems. The only annoying here is eclipse telling me, there is no method "test"..

Comment: Did you take a look on this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674258/eclipse-method-could-not-be-resolved-for-vector-of-vectors. Maybe there is the problem?

Comment: Good idea, but I created now several projects with nearly all combinations of c++11 activation in the project settings. All holding just the (second) test code shown above and either they don't know the std::thread or they don't know the methods inside the vector items..

Comment: What about : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905025/string-could-not-resolved-error-in-eclipse-for-c or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977542/eclipse-cdt-unresolved-inclusion-of-stl-header, did you try anything?

Comment: Both tested without success :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Eclipse set up but the problem appears to be around `std::string`.  Does the problem go away if you remove the threading from the example?  (I also changed to `#include <string>` instead of string.h)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

#if 0
void test() {
    vector<string> myvector;
    string a("Teststring");
    myvector.push_back(a);
    cout << myvector.begin()->length() << endl;
}
#endif

int main() {
    //thread(test).join();
    vector<string> myvector;
    string a("Teststring");
    myvector.push_back(a);
    cout << myvector.begin()->length() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

That should hopefully print out `10`.

**Update from comment:**

Does this generate the Eclipse warning?

```
auto tmp = *(myvector.begin());
std::cout << tmp.length() << std::endl;
```

What about this?

```
std::string foo("abc123");
std::cout << foo.length() << std::endl;
```

I guess one more too:

```
std::string foo2 = *(myvector.begin());
std::cout << foo2.length() << std::endl;
```

Comment: It does print out 10, but the error in eclipse is still the same: **Method 'length' could not be resolved**

Comment: The first ends up with the same error. The second one works (you missed a : after the first std) and gives me the length of this string.

Comment: The third version works! But will I have to access every method in that way?

Comment: Edited in the first post, there must be a way to access these methods without casting, the compile has no problem with that, just eclipse keeps claiming..

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a setting that can be tweaked.  It looks like Eclipse can't tell a function or class's API without the type spelled out exactly in the code.  I hope there's another way for you.

Comment: I had to enable the c++11, therefore the thread method in the demo code. There must be anybode out there, that is using eclipse (Juno) with c++11 (gcc4.7//ubuntu12.10) and has no problems in using vectors and threads (std)?!!

Answer (score 0):

**The solution found:**

I downloaded eclipse kepler [Kepler](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php)

Created a new project and tried to compile this source code (like above):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

class TestClass {
public:
    void test() {
        cout << "test" << endl;
    }
};

void test() {
    vector<TestClass> testClassVector;
    TestClass x;
    testClassVector.push_back(x);
    testClassVector.begin()->test();
}

int main() {
    thread(test).join();
    return 0;
}
```

On the first run eclipse told me, thread belongs to the new c++11 standard and I have to add  **-std=c++11** to the compiler flags. To use thread I also added **-pthread** to the linker flags. With this steps the code could be compiled, but eclipse marks the thread still as unknown. To fix this I proceeded the following step:

*Under C/C++ Build (at project settings), find the Preprocessor Include Path and go to the Providers Tab. Deselect all except CDT GCC Builtin Compiler Settings. Then untag Share settings entries … . Add the option -std=c++11 to the text box called Command to get compiler specs.*

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support).

Now - unbelievable but true - it works, even without any errors marked by eclipse. The solution is using the (beta) version of eclipse, wich seems to handle this in a better way.

Thanks for all your help!